# React Native - upload image to Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

First I create a blob file

```
  RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(localImgUrl2, 'base64')
    .then(base64ImageStr => Blob.build('image.png', base64ImageStr, { type: 'image/png;BASE64' }))
```

......then i try to upload to firebase

```
    .then((data) => {FBStorageRef.put(data, { contentType: mime })})
```

...but it gives me the error

```
Firebase Storage: Object 'profilePics/image.png' does not exist
```

I believe its my `FBStorageRef` that it has a beef with.....my cloud storage is totally empty and I want to create a folder called profilePics.......and the file within I want to call image.png

```
const FBStorageRef = Firebase.storage().ref('/profilePics/image.png');
```

It says that `profilePics/image.png doe not exist` which is true enough.....but thats exactly why I want to upload it right :)

Comment: Hey James, I use firebase storage to save images, this way right? I just take a photo URI from the picker and save it to firebase as image ".jpg"!

Comment: Please refer https://medium.com/@davidjsehl/react-native-and-the-infamous-blob-uploading-images-to-firebase-b1a440f9e078

Comment: Yes @hongdevelop Ive read this article - unfortunately does not help......If you compare my code versus the article you will see it is mirrored very closely.  However I have a feeling this issue is only related to uploading images to Firebase.....dont think theres anything wrong with code that uses rn-fetch-blob

Comment: Hello James, did you check the "Rules" section? What do you have as a configuration? Maybe permissions or invalid configuration :)

Comment: I did Yes - rules are set for dev so anyone can read/write

Answer (score 3):

1. If the file path looks like `file:///...`. You can just simple put it to Firebase function, don't need readFile step.

My code works properly up to now:

```
  static uploadProfileAvatar(userID, fileURI) { // file URI is a path of a local image
    const updateTime = moment().unix();
    const storagePath = `${PROFILE_AVATAR_PATH}/${userID}_${updateTime}.jpg`;
    const fileMetaData = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' };
    return FirebaseStorage.uploadFile(fileURI, storagePath, fileMetaData);
  }

  static uploadFile(fileURI, storagePath, fileMetaData = null) {
    const uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref().child(storagePath).put(fileURI, fileMetaData);
    return uploadTask;
  }
```

2. If you have the path like `rct-image-store://0`. You have to write it and then get the local path image. After that upload local image as case 1

```
  ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(
    rctFileURI, // rct-image-store: path
    (base64Image) => {
      const imagePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`;
      RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, `${base64Image}`, 'base64')
      .then((success) => {
        // now your file path is imagePath (which is a real path)
        if (success) {
          // upload with imagePath, same as the 1
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {});
    },
    () => {},
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RNFirebase for handling firebase storage upload and download. check the below link for more details about installation.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/master/packages/storage

then upload a file using below code

```
 import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

  export const uploadMediaUri = (uri, path) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.storage()
            .ref(path)
            .putFile(uri)
            .then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
            .catch(e => {
                reject(e)
            });
    })
}
```

Here  `uri` is the local path that which file you want to upload
and `path` is the upload path of firebase storage

Comment: Hi Vinayak - this looks promising thanks.....however I installed package as per git instructions (npm install @react-native-firebase/storage --save) then imported with "import rnFb from '@react-native-firebase/storage'";.....but its giving me the error "@react-native-firebase/app/lib.common does not exist in the Haste module map"....can you help?

Comment: Check @react-native-firebase/storage in node_module folder. if it there then restart your metro builder and run again

Comment: Yes - storage file is there....restart doesnt help unfortunately.  Also although there is a "storage" folder there is no "app" folder (which is what the error appears to be complaining about)